# How can i remove the duplicated elements in my array?

Tags: javascript

I used this code but with that i can only remove the next one and the previuous one if its equal

```
 for (let i = 0; i < this.userlist.length; i++) {
      if (this.userlist[i] == this.userlist[i+1])
        this.userlist.splice(i+1, 1);
      if (this.userlist[i-1] == this.userlist[i+1])
        this.userlist.splice(i+1, 1);
    }
```

How can i remove all the duplicated elements?

edit n°1

```
 data() {
return {
  formlogin: "",
  userID: "Guest",
  logged: false,
  userlist: []
  };
  },
 mounted() {
  this.userID = localStorage.getItem("userID");
  if (this.userID != "Guest") this.logged = localStorage.getItem("logged");
  if (localStorage.userlist)
  this.userlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userlist"));
 },

 props: {},

  methods: {
  login: function() {
  if (this.formlogin != "") {
    this.userID = this.formlogin;
    this.formlogin = "";
    this.logged = true;
    localStorage.setItem("logged", this.logged);
    localStorage.setItem("userID", this.userID);

    this.userlist.push(this.userID);

    for (let i = 0; i < this.userlist.length; i++) {
      if (this.userlist[i] == this.userlist[i + 1])
        this.userlist.splice(i + 1, 1);
      if (this.userlist[i - 1] == this.userlist[i + 1])
        this.userlist.splice(i + 1, 1);
      
    }
    localStorage.setItem("userlist", JSON.stringify(this.userlist));
    console.log("data sent :", this.userID, this.logged);
    alert("Welcome : " + this.userID);
  } else alert("cant login with a null username");
},
```

thats how my userlist will be updated.

Comment: can you show an example of userlist ? i mean what is inside user

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: ES6 have  ```new Set()``` which removes all duplicates

Comment: My userlist initially is empty each time a user does a login the list will populate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`es6` ***spread*** operator with `Set()`

```js
var items = [4,5,4,6,3,4,5,2,23,1,4,4,4];
console.log([...new Set(items)]);
```

***OR***,

```js
var items = [4,5,4,6,3,4,5,2,23,1,4,4,4];
console.log(Array.from(new Set(items)));
```

Using `filter` method

```js
var items = [4,5,4,6,3,4,5,2,23,1,4,4,4];
var newItems = items.filter((item, i) => items.indexOf(item) === i);
console.log(newItems);
```

Using `reduce` method

```js
var items = [4,5,4,6,3,4,5,2,23,1,4,4,4];
var newItems = items.reduce((uniq, item) => uniq.includes(item) ? uniq: [...uniq, item], []);
console.log(newItems);
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Simple and Straight. Thumbs Up :)

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it!

```js
for (let i = 0; i < this.userlist.length; i++) {
  if (this.userlist[i] == this.userlist[i+1]){
    this.userlist.splice(i+1, 1);
    i--;
  }
}
```

In your solution, two elements are removed at most. What you can do instead is remove the next element an make sure that the index doesn't increase (hence the `i--`, so in the next iteration `if` will check the same index again).

This however only works for sorted lists. Check solanki's answer for a more generic one.

Comment: But if i add the same id two position next it will result as a non duplicated and will be added normally

Comment: As said, your implementation only works on sorted lists. You can either sort the array first or use the `Set` solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce` you can do something like this. Check if the current index is same as the first index found in `data`

```js
var data = ["user", "user", "user", "foo", "foo"]

var res = data.reduce((acc, elem, idx, arr)=> (arr.indexOf(elem) === idx ? [...acc, elem] : acc),[]);

console.log(res)
```